# grep user name in unix

Tags: unix

I want to grep the username.
the command id gives the following.
id    output is
uid=0(root) gid=0(root)

but i want the output as only root or who ever the user is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a grep, that's a [cut](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut):

```
$ id | cut -d '(' -f 2 | cut -d ')' -f 1
```

If you're doing this in a script (as a comment implies), you need to capture the output of the command properly. In bash, use:

```
USER=$(id | cut -d '(' -f 2 | cut -d ')' -f 1)
```

Many o(th|ld)er shells support the backtick syntax:

```
USER=`id | cut -d '(' -f 2 | cut -d ')' -f 1`
```

Comment: when i use it in a script , it displays nothing

                      
#!/bin/bash
Userid=id | cut -d '(' -f 2 | cut -d ')' -f 1
echo $Userid

Answer (score 0):

```
id -un
```

will directly print the name associated with the current effective user-id.

Comment: it stays illegal option --u . im using solaris